# Link external library CMakeLists.txt on Windows

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, sfml

I'm trying to realize a CMakeLists.txt to compile my project under Linux and Windows. I use two libraries : SFML and boost. However, I want that my project can be built under Linux or Windows without the installation of libraries from a user.

I explain. Libraries SFML and boost are compiled and placed in my folder project and I want that no matter on which computer I download my project, I can build it.

And here is my problem, I can't link externally from the libraries folder in my folder project, the SFML and boost libraries.

Here is my CMakeLists.txt :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

project(r-type_client CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++14")

include_directories(./boost/include
        ./SFML/include
        ./include
        )

if(UNIX)

set(BOOST_LIBRARY
-L./boost/linux
-lboost_regex
)

set(SFML_LIBRARY
-L./SFML/linux
-lsfml-graphics
-lsfml-window
-lsfml-system
)

add_executable(r-type_client
       srcs/Main.cpp
       )

target_link_libraries(r-type_client
          ${BOOST_LIBRARY}
          ${SFML_LIBRARY}
          )

elseif(WIN32)

add_library(bar SHARED IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET bar PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION        
C:/Users/Hugo/Downloads/Old/client/SFML/windows/sfml-graphics.dll)
set_property(TARGET bar PROPERTY IMPORTED_IMPLIB         
C:/Users/Hugo/Downloads/Old/client/SFML/windows/sfml-graphics.lib)
add_library(bor SHARED IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET bor PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION 
C:/Users/Hugo/Downloads/Old/client/SFML/windows/sfml-window.dll)
set_property(TARGET bor PROPERTY IMPORTED_IMPLIB 
C:/Users/Hugo/Downloads/Old/client/SFML/windows/sfml-window.lib)
add_library(bur SHARED IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET bur PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION 
C:/Users/Hugo/Downloads/Old/client/SFML/windows/sfml-system.dll)
set_property(TARGET bur PROPERTY IMPORTED_IMPLIB 
C:/Users/Hugo/Downloads/Old/client/SFML/windows/sfml-system.lib)
add_executable(r-type_client srcs/Main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(r-type_client bar bor bur)

endif(UNIX)
```

Comment: `SFML_LIBRARY` should be just the names of the libraries to link.

Comment: `BOOST_LIBRARY` cmake already has support for boost. Use it.

Comment: You should do the IMPORTED stuff before target_link_libraries

Comment: @drescherjm My problem is for Windows not Linux

Comment: You should set up your CMake project in a proper way by using `find_package()` to properly locate everything. The way you're doing it now is prone to errors (as you experience) and not really portable. If you're hardcoding everything, it would be far easier to just setup a MSVC project for example. You're using CMake, but you're basically working around it completely.

Answer (score 2):

As I've mentioned in the comments, you should set up your CMake project in a proper way by using `find_package()` to properly locate everything.

CMake is a tool to allow people to creation files needed for compilation on the fly no matter the host system. By hardcoding paths and (unneeded) per-platform branches, you're basically negating the whole purpose of CMake.

To include a third party library in CMake, you'll typically want to use `find_package()`, which includes the necessary logic to locate the library and setup variables properly (it essentially does what you've done by hand so far).

Let's do it for SFML, since it's basically the same for Boost (and I don't really have Boost ready to test everything, because the variable names might differ from project to project).

First, you'll tell CMake that your project wants to use SFML:

```
find_package(SFML)
```

Depending on the actual "package", you can extend this. In SFML's case we can even define which minimum version we want and which sub libraries we actually want to use:

```
find_package(SFML 2.3 COMPONENTS graphics window system REQUIRED)
```

The `REQUIRED` flag makes the whole thing mandatory, i.e. CMake will error out, if it's not found.

Once this line succeeded, it will have set a few variables with the proper paths and libraries, which we can then use when defining a target:

```
include_directories(${SFML_INCLUDE_DIR})
add_executable(myprogram ${MY_SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(myprogram ${SFML_LIBRARIES} ${SFML_DEPENDENCIES})
```

And you're done. As you can see, I can setup a CMake project in less than 10 lines without any platform specific paths, code, or knowledge.

However, when running this, you'll most likely run into one error:

CMake by default might not be able to find a `FindSFML.cmake` file and complain.

You'll find this file in your SFML directory under the `cmake` path. Copy it to your project and tell CMake where to look for it, for example:

```
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")
```

Once this is done as well, CMake might not be able to locate the actual SFML files, especially on Windows. To tell it where to look for it, you'd define `SFML_ROOT` when invoking CMake:

```
cmake -DSFML_ROOT=C:/Users/Hugo/Downloads/Old/client/SFML path/to/source
```

This gives you the big advantage that you won't have to hardcode the path to SFML (or any other library such as Boost). On your linux machine, you typically won't even have to provide any path and everything should just work out of the box.

Comment: I just tried what you said and I got this with other errors :

undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf6StringC1EPKcRKSt6locale'

Comment: Are you using the correct binaries for your compiler?

Comment: @drescherjm Yes, I use the 32-bits version and it doesn't work. I tried to add #define SFML_STATIC and the errors changed : 

undefined reference to `sf::String::String(char const*, std::locale const&)'

Comment: I compiled with the command prompt of VS2017 in 32-bits and already the same errors

Comment: @Meugiwara Are you sure you didn't forget SFML-System and you've got the correct order?